# Unwanted Selection Events In ListView

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, winrt-xaml

How do I prevent a ListView selection change event from firing when I only want the bound data to change?

To clarify, I have classes like this:

```
public class MyCollectionViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> MyItems { get; set; }

    private MyItemViewModel _selectedItem;
    public MyItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);

            if (_selectedItem != null)
            {
                // Do something...
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}

public class MyItemViewModel : BindableBase
{
        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set { this.SetProperty(ref _isSelected, value); }
        }
        ...
}
```

With the following data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Margin="10" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Border Grid.Column="1">
            ...
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

... and used like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SessionsViewSource}}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Sessions.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          IsSwipeEnabled="False" />
```

To somewhat visualize the ListView:

> ```
>    +---------------------
>    + [x]  myItem1
>    +---------------------
>    + [ ]  myItem2
>    +---------------------
> ```

The user can check and uncheck the checkboxes. Problem is, if there's an existing selection, when the `IsSelected` binding updates, the selection binding happens as well.

Is there a simple way to fix this?  I'd like to stick with MVVM as much as possible.

Comment: Apologies... I didn't see that tag.

Comment: I actually tagged it with WPF causing the confusion. Removed it now.

Comment: Please Explain this sentence `if there's an existing selection, when the IsSelected binding updates, the selection binding happens as well`

Comment: Here's the scenario: (1) user selects an item (2) selection event happens (3) user clicks on the checkbox from a different item to tag (4) unwanted selection event happens. Basically, when the checkbox from a different item is clicked, I don't want a selection change event.

Comment: I could probably do this the non-MVVM way, but I'm trying to find out if it's at all possible in MVVM.

Comment: As you are using MVVM, try adding to check the box using code behing instead of using Mouse Click. if the selectionchanged event not fired on code behind. then use the Selectionchanged Event in you view.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your property with

```
public MyItemViewModel SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        if (value.IsSelected)
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        }
        // Optional: if you require
        else
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, null);
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not it. I'm trying to avoid generating a selection change event when the bound checkbox value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `SelectedItem="{Binding Sessions.SelectedItem}"` It's not required you'll receive the proper selections from the checkbox binding.  You should also changed the ListView SelectionMode to None.  It's confusing because your property is called IsSelected.  Name it IsChecked, focus on that and remove any selection functionality.  You might even be able to downgrade to and ItemsControl over the ListView.

Comment: Thanks, but the binding to the selected item still has to happen (i.e. tapping on the item opens details on the item, tapping on the checkbox only selects the checkbox).

Comment: I'm able to workaround this by having a tapped event handler that ignores the event if it came in via the checkbox. Not ideal but works. I have a feeling I'm actually doing it wrong...